container is stuck in state "stopping", cannot clear it
I have a container stuck in "stopping" state:
% podman container ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                          COMMAND     CREATED      STATUS      ...
40aaa25d12c5  docker.io/ubuntu/bind9:latest  /bin/bash   2 hours ago  Stopping    ...

Trying "podman stop" (no effect) or "podman kill" ("container not running") are failing.
I read a thread on GITHUB with the same case:
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/19629
this would have been resolved in May/2024 with some fixes in libpod.
=> is this bug known as well to Ubuntu developers? And -if so- is this correction in "podman" planned to happen via an upgrade of Ubuntu packages?
Info:

ubuntu 24.04 (kernel 6.8.0-31-generic)
podman version 4.9.3

